# how to fill particular indices of a dimension of tensor with a constant value k in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensor

I am trying to find a way to replace certain indices of a dimension in tensor with a constant value k. Something similar to index_fill_ in PyTorch.

I have checked tensor_scatter_nd_update, but that requires the entire tensor along with the indices and values to be replaced. Which requires the indices to be with respect to the whole tensor but not just one particular dimension and also requires the values to be in the form of a tensor rather than just a single constant. I am looking for something simpler?

If anyone knows any of this, can you please provide some solution or a direction in which i should be looking into? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given an example but you could slice and assign like this.

```
import tensorflow as tf

aa = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10, 4]))
tensor = tf.constant(10,shape=(4,3))
aa[0:4, 1:4 ].assign(tf.ones_like(tensor, dtype=tf.float32))
print(aa)

aa[0:4, 1:4 ].assign([[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]])
print(aa)
```

Both formats of *assign* print this.

```
 array([[0., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)>
```